# Как сгруппировать данные, что бы каждой дате соответствовало только одно уникальное имя (пример на рис)

Tags: excel

Как сгруппировать данные, что бы каждой дате соответствовало только одно уникальное имя (пример на рис)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Удалить дубликаты".

Comment: не могу вставить пример таблицы, редактор муть какую то предлагает

Comment: если я воспользуесь удалением дубликатов, удалятся уникальные значения из соседнего столбца

Comment: Из какого - соседнего? в примере нет никаких дополнительных столбцов. Я уж не говорю о том, что ничто не запрещает указать только отдельные столбцы или вообще регион для удаления дубликатов.

Comment: покажите пример. я вас не понимаю. простое удаление дубликатов - он удалит все дубликаты и останутся две строчки.

Comment: "останутся две строчки" - это в смысле Иван и Елена? Ну да, если удалять дублирующиеся "Дата". А если удалять дублирующиеся "Name" и "Дата", то результат будет как на картинке

Comment: нет, тогда останутся три строчки. Иван, Сергей, Елена

Comment: Вы лучше попробуйте, чем пургу-то нести... а ещё лучше - предварительно почитайте справку по операции.

Comment: Там для одного  имени несколько дат....

Comment: попробовал прежде чем писать, разные комбинации (их может быть три). а вы попробовали?

Comment: Еще функция UNIQUE не работает. Ошибка в Имя пишет, странно, в powershell Unique с эпохи динозавров используется, в excel в 21 году появилась -пишут. у меня самый самый последний офис.

Comment: почему в excel есть отличия русской версии от английской, в смысле в одной надо в формулах одни знаки писать в другой версии - другие. это что бы новичкам было трудно наверно.

Comment: Правильно заданный вопрос содержит в себе половину ответа. А тут я вообще задачи не понял

Comment: *одной надо в формулах одни знаки писать в другой версии - другие.* - потому что в разных локлизациях разные разделители. Как, кстати, и разделители целой и дробной части в числах. Если откроете формулу, написанную в английской локали, у себя на русской, формула будет отображаться нормально (с разделителями, принятым в русской локали)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавить формулу в столбец С (в `C2`) и протянуть по строкам с данными:

**=A2&"_"&B2**

Выделить столбец С, закладка *Данные-Удалить дубликаты-Автоматически расширить диапазон-Удалить дубликаты-(окошко  для отметки столбцов  и с галкой о заголовках)-ОК*.

Удалить вспомогательный столбец

---

При динамических данных.

Добавляем еще одну формулу:

```
=ЕСЛИ(A2<>"";ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ($C$2:C2;C2)=1;МАКС($D$1:D1)+1))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На листе с результатом в отдельной ячейке  А2 (чтобы не считать в каждой формуле) определяем количество уникальных:

```
=МАКС(Лист1!D2:D200)
```

Нумеруем записи (столбец В):

```
=ЕСЛИ(СТРОКА(A1)>МАКС(Лист1!$D$2:$D$200);;СТРОКА(A1))
```

Получаем имена (столбец С):

```
=ЕСЛИ($B2>0;ИНДЕКС(Лист1!$A$2:$B$200;ПОИСКПОЗ(СТРОКА(Лист1!A1);Лист1!D:D;);1);)
```

Для подтягивания дат та же формула, только изменить последнюю единичку на двойку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Убрать "некрасивые" нули:

закладка *Файл-Параметры_Дополнительно-Для листа*, снять галку отображения нулевых значений

При большом количестве строк лучше это все выводить с помощью VBA

Comment: Задумка хорошая. Но автоматом как это сделать что бы работало? Данные все время обновляются и плюс увеличиваются. То есть нужна такая формула, которая на свежий лист копирует столбецA и СтолбецB но уже с отфильтрованными данными.

Comment: Короче VBA уже тут нужен, идут динамические данные.

Answer (score 0):

Вот как я сделал:

```
1. Формула для столбца C, ставим на C2 =ТЕКСТ(B2;"дд.ММ.гггг")&A2  [меням по ходу тип Дата на Текст, что бы сцепка была понятной]
2. Форомула для столбца D, ставим на D2 =ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ($D$2:$D2; $D2)>1; "Дубликат"; "Уникально")
3. Фильтруем по столбцу D текстовым фильтром Текст содержит "Уникально"
```

Comment: Преобразование в дату лишнее. Это Вам непривычно видеть пятизначное число, а это и есть дата в десятичном формате и Excel прекрасно это понимает. И чем Ваши формулы отличаются от тех, которые показаны на 3 дня раньше? Да и решение идентичное (там можно фильтровать по столбцу D по условию "больше нуля")

Comment: я один день был так погружен в разработку, что когда зашел снова на форум увидел несколько решений и тем не менее моё решение уже решил оставить. -про преобразование в текст формат - согласен, нет крайней необходимости.